# \textsubscript undefined in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, subscripts, fixltx2e

Beamer tells me `\textsubscript` is undefined. Isn't it a core LaTeX command? How can I use the command in Beamer?

This example throws "undefined control sequence" errors and does not subscript the numbers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\octave}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Musical octaves are designated with subscript numbers:
A\octave{1}, A\octave{2}, A\octave{3}, and so on.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**ANSWER/WARNING**

The package `fixltx2e` provides a `\textsubscript` command.

The `memoir` document class (and probably others) loads `fixltx2e` by default; `beamer` does not. If you want to write a package that you can use in both classes, adding `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` can cause problems with any class that already loads that package.

But if `\textsubscript` is the only reason for loading `fixltx2e`, then it is better to use the `subscript` package instead.

Comment: You need `fixltx2e` for `\textsubscript`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Up till now I have been using this with `memoir` class, which must load `fixltx2e` automatically, so I didn't realize.