# \textsubscript no longer works with xetex

Tags: xetex, subscripts

The command `\textsubscript` used to work with `xelatex` (at least until sometime in the fall of 2014), but now it throws this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textsubscript unavailable in encoding EU1.
```

How can I work around this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
1\textsubscript{2}3
\end{document}
```

I'm running XeTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 in TeX Live 2014.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode (also duplicated in my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226697/textsubscript-undefined-in-beamer)

Comment: I don't know why this worked before. You need either `fixltx2e` or `subscript` packages to get the `\textsubscript` command.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Well that explains it. The latest version of ``fontspec`` no longer loads ``fixltx2e``, cf. the [readme](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/README).