# LuaLaTeX from texlive-2014: Command \textsubscript unavailable in encoding EU2

Tags: luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

Here is a minimal example of a file that `lualatex` from texlive-2013 compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
X\textsubscript{Y}
\end{document}
```

If I try to compile it with `lualatex` from texlive-2014 [as packaged by Debian 8 "Jessie"](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/texlive-latex-base), I get the following error:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (rev 4971) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 13 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-compat.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-modutils.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-loader.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.loader.lua))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-regs.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-attr.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/attr.lua))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-cctb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/cctb.lua))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-mcb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-fontloader.lua)(
using write cache: /home/david/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using read cache
: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic /home/david/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generi
c)
luaotfload | main : fontloader loaded in 0.030 seconds
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-override.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-parsers.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-configuration.lu
a)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-status.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-loaders.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-colors.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-features.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-letterspace.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-auxiliary.lua))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.lua)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd)(compiling luc: /var/li
b/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/da
vid/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-regular.luc))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def(compiling luc: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-
cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmromanslant10-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/david/.texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmromanslant10-regular.luc)(compiling luc: /
var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-italic.luc)(load luc: /ho
me/david/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-italic.luc)(compili
ng luc: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-bold.luc)(load l
uc: /home/david/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-bold.luc)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmss.fd)(compiling luc: /var/l
ib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmsans10-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/da
vid/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmsans10-regular.luc))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua))))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
No file test.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! LaTeX Error: Command \textsubscript unavailable in encoding EU2.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 X\textsubscript
                 {Y}
? x
 296 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 rule, 1 kern, 1 glyph, 3 attribute, 41 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 temp, 1 write, 1 local_par, 1 dir nodes
   avail lists: 2:9,3:1,4:2,7:1,9:1
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I did find [this related tex.stackexchange thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78766/command-nobreakspace-unavailable-in-encoding-eu1-if-i-use-xelatex), but I its solution is not applicable here since I *only* load fontspec.

Here are my questions:

- Is this a bug, or did I do something wrong?
- If it is a bug, is it worth bug-reporting somewhere?  If so, where?  (Debian, texlive, luatex, latex, or some subset of the above?)
- Is there some not-too-ugly way to work around this bug?  Assume, for various reasons, that I really need to work with this particular version of lualatex/texlive (and, unforunately, given Debian's hard-line policy of not fixing bugs unless they are security holes, this will remain as such until the next version of Debian is released, approximately one trillion years from now).  Is there something I can write to make \textsubscript "available under EU2 encoding" which wouldn't break if it already works?

Thanks for any help!

**Clarification:** The question has been satisfactorily answered by David Carlisle below.  I don't see, however, how it can be considered a duplicate of [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode): in my minimal example, `\textsubscript` works with `luatex` from texlive-2013, so my question was not "how to produce a subscript?" but "how/why did the behavior change between 2013 and 2014? (and is this a bug?)".  Furthermore, I emphasize that the error message I got, which is reproduced in the title, **was not** "Undefined control sequence" (if it were, the question would, indeed, be a duplicate).  As a matter of fact, I'd be curious to have an explanation of this error message: how can someone have coded a specific error message saying that `\textsubscript` is "unavailable" (what does that even *mean*?) when the fix is almost as short as the error message itself — this seems to make no sense.

Comment: I've raised [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228518/textsubscript-no-longer-works-with-xetex) before.

Comment: Your minimal document only contains the command `\textsubscript`, and this gives you the error `Command \textsubscript unavailable in encoding ...`. You wondered why this is, and what you could do about it. That's _exactly_ the same question as [I have asked before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228518/textsubscript-no-longer-works-with-xetex), so it's a duplicate. Since my question itself was closed as a dupe, I voted to close yours as a dupe of the _original_ question. Your question can't be marked as a dupe of my question, since it doesn't have an answer (it got resolved in the com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the 2015/01/01 latex release, it's not needed, but for 2014, the easiest way to get `\textsubscript` defined is

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
X\textsubscript{Y}
\end{document}
```

Older releases of `fontspec` included `fixltx2e` automatically, that was removed at some point, and in latex 2015 release, `fixltx2e` is not needed at all.

If you don't want all of `fixltx2e` just steal the one definition:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{%
  \@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This does indeed fix my minimal example.  Sadly, `fixltx2e` seems to break other things, because now the combination of `biblatex` and `\footnote` produces the message "Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.", and calls to `\footnote` break.☹  Do you think this can be fixed as well (should I open another thread?) or will I keep on running on more problems as I fix them?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen see update

Comment: Wonderful!, it worked.  Thank you very much.